# highlight column only in table css/html

Tags: html, css

[1]I have this table that on hover should highlight the columns. But right now it only highlights one `<td>` I am aware that the reasons it happens is because I only called the `<thead>` in my css. I have also search in google on how to highlight the columns but none of them worked. Can someone help? I have attached my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/amo4w5aj/1/)

Comment: please feed your css in fiddle

Comment: you want to highlight full column or one cell at a time?

Comment: yes. full column. @Shivam

Comment: @anna - You will need JavaScript or jQuery for this.

Comment: yes you can make it by using this.. http://css-tricks.com/row-and-column-highlighting/

Comment: `table tr:hover td {background: rgba(0, 140, 203, 0.2);}`Updated Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/shanidkv/amo4w5aj/7/

Comment: hey you can't change background color of column on hover in css. you can change row color. In javascript it is possible use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in CSS:

```
table tr td:hover {
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your CSS, like:

```
.tblPackage tr:hover{background: green}
```

Comment: This highlights rows and _not_ columns. How does this help the OP?

Comment: My bad, I misread it. @Sarath's answer is the most accurate for it.